# Find one and insert into child referenced document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a User model, with a referenced child array of objects, I would like to find the User, and **insert** into the child referenced document, I don't want to update the child document, but rather insert another object into the reports document array.

Below is the User model, I basically want to **find the User**, and **insert into Reports**.

```
const User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    dateOfBirth: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    agreedToTerms: Boolean,
    agreementDate: String,
    verified: Boolean,
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role"
      }
    ],
    reports: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Reports"
      }
    ]
  })
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findByIdAndUpdate` with `$push`:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(<user-id>, {
    $push: { reports: <report-id> }
});
```

Comment: when you mention <report-id> are you stating that the full object I'm trying to insert should be in this place?

Comment: @MQ You have defined `reports` as an `ObjectId` `ref` property so you should insert only the reference to the report (its `_id` field). If you need to store the whole object you will need to change your schema declaration.